# How to Typescript mongoose toObject?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

What is the correct way of typing `.toObject()` return?

```js
const userDoc = await UsersModel.findOne({email})
const user:IUserObject = userDoc.toObject()
```

The `user` is not `IUserObject`. Its typing doesn't make sense: `Pick<Pick<_LeanDocument<IUserModel>, "_id"...`.

Here is my model typing:

```js
import {Schema, model, Document} from 'mongoose'

export interface IUser {
  email: string
  password: string
}

export interface IUserObject extends IUser {
  _id: string
}

export interface IUserModel extends Document, IUser {}

const schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
})

export const UsersModel = model<IUserModel>('Users', schema)
```

Comment: I dont think theres a good answer here. The types declarations for mongoose are unclear and unwieldy. You can either coerce the type to your interface or use the mongoose computed type. I would say that I think theres a lot of benefit to validating data retrieved from the database which invites one to write a function validateRetrieved(data: unknown): IUser which happens to solve your initial problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose original type for `doc.toObject()` looks really convoluted and most likely comes from time before conditional types and `infer` operator. Even worse it seems to be incorrect representation of the runtime value, which according to [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) should be just POJO:

```
type ToObjectReturnType = ReturnType<Document<IUser>['toObject']>
/*
  ToObjectReturnType = {
    _id?: IUser;
    __v?: number;
    id?: any;
  }
*/
```

A possible solution / improvement without fixing underlying problem in mongoose could be using an auxiliary function to infer underlying model from the document and make a call to `doc.toObject`:

```
// a generic method for infering underlying Model out of a mongoose Document
// and interecting it with { _id: string }
const docToObject = <D extends Document<any>>(doc: D) =>
  doc.toObject() as D extends Document<infer Model>
    ? Model & { _id: string } // not sure if _id is always there - please modify to your needs / real runtime value
    : never;

// example of usage
const findUserByEmail = async (email: string) => {
  const userDoc = await UsersModel.findOne({ email });
  return docToObject(userDoc);
};
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-orketk)

#### remark

Please mind - that according to [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) - it is possible to configure `.toObject` on the schema level and/or pass params when calling `.toObject`. To properly type these use cases is out of scope of this question or not possible with current Typescript version altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Omit<>` and replace the type declaration of toObject

```
export interface IUserModel extends Omit<Document, 'toObject'>, IUser {
      toObject: () => IUserObject;
}
```