# Typescript & mongo models

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically I have this method that I use on my repository:

```js
async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<User | null> {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({
            email
        });

        if(!user) return null;

        const obj = user.toObject();
        
        obj.id // error property 'id' does not exist on type
}
```

I have two models, one mongo model and one normal model (type), this is the mongo model, and I created a virtuals to replace the `_id` with `id`:

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: String
}, {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true,
        transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
            ret.id = ret._id;
            delete ret.__v;
            delete ret._id;
        }
    },
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true,
        transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
            ret.id = ret._id;
            delete ret.__v;
            delete ret._id;
        }
    }
});

export const User = mongoose.model('user', schema);
```

This is the domain model:

```js
export type User = {
    id: string,
    email: string,
    password: string
}
```

I keep getting `property 'id' does not exist on type` error on the `findByEmail` fucntion, any ideas (i don't want to create a UserDocument interface that extends mongoose.Document because the i'm trying to use Clean Architecture, and i think the model shouldn't be aware of database things)

Comment: Shouldn't your `transform` function have `return ret`? If you cast `ret` to your domain `User` type or use `transform: (doc, ret, options): DomainUser { ... }` does it work?

Comment: It did not work, also, its not a error, its a ts warning, if i use // @ts-ignore, it works, but i think its not a good approach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Typescript mongoose toObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897965/how-to-typescript-mongoose-toobject). It doesn't look like `toObject` is a good way to convert from documents to domain objects

Comment: Actually no, but i fixed it by looking mongoose wiki, i basically need to type both schema and model:

new mongoose.Schema<User>({})
mongoose.model<User>('user', schema);

Comment: Feel free to post an answer below, it sounds helpful

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by typing the schema & model
Like:

```ts
const schema = new mongoose.Schema<User>({});

const UserModel = mongoose.model<User>('user', schema);
```